# Disable CTRL+ALT+F4 switching to virtual terminal

Tags: shortcut-keys, virtualization, virtual-terminal

Is there a way that I can stop the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> key combination from switching to a virtual terminal?  I **still** want the other key combinations to switch to terminals - I just want to change the <kbd>F4</kbd> one because I often use that keyboard shortcut in a Windows VM.

Comment: You can use Host + F4 to issue a Ctrl + Alt + F4 for the VM (assuming VirtualBox)

Comment: You might be able to remove tty4 from the getty list, but not sure it wouldn't push 5, 6, 7, etc. down. If you can live with 1 VT, your X server, and a log window, you can probably cram it all into F1, F2, F3. I forget the file you edit, that's why this is a comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can modify the keymap, with the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke | sed -n 's/ = .*VT_4.*/ = /p' | xmodmap -
```

Tested on 14.04, and 14.10, and it works.  To have the command work even after restart, use [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/wiki/).  For additional ways, and info see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)

Comment: Should this take effect immediately?

Comment: Hmm, I executed this and ran `xmodmap -pke | grep 'keycode\s*70'` to verify it was gone.  Ctrl-alt-F4 still switches to the terminal, and more interestingly, any time I switch to a TTY, the setting is reset.  Please note, I ran the above in a gnome console window

Comment: Uhm, it works for me. If disabled in the host, when executed in the guest it switch to the ubuntu guest vt4. If disabled also in the guest I have no effect at all.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 using compiz Window Manager.  Not sure why this isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

On Gnome Wayland you can unset this keybinding for virtual terminal switching by setting this dconf property:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/mutter/wayland/keybindings/switch-to-session-4 "['']"
```