# Prevent Ctrl+Alt+F4 from switching TTYs

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, virtual-terminal

> Related: [Disable CTRL+ALT+F4 switching to virtual terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/50233/disable-ctrlaltf4-switching-to-virtual-terminal)

I would like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> for a program instead of Ubuntu's TTYs.

The previous question, I saw suggested command `xmodmap -pke | sed -n 's/ = .*VT_4.*/ = /p' | xmodmap -` which did not work for me. I ran it with Alt+F2.

Comment: Try not running it with Alt+F2 try running it in a terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will disable a few more key sequences than just the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> shortcuts, but should do what you want.

1. Open the *Keyboard* configuration tool.

   [image]
2. Switch to the *Layouts* tab and click the *Options...*  button.

   [image]
3. Expand the *Miscellaneous compatibility options* section and check the box next to
   *Special keys (Ctrl+Alt+) handled in a server*.

   [image]

   The effect should be instant and persist when you log in again.

This also disables a few other server shortcuts such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> / <kbd>-</kbd> to switch video modes.