# How to disable "ctrl + alt + Fn" shortcut?

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'd like to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut (in Eclipse), but it's caught by Ubuntu and I cannot find, how to disable it.

Thanks

Comment: This is a duplicate of this [question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/50855/prevent-ctrlaltf4-from-switching-ttys).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go to *`System settings...`* -> *`Keyboard Layout`* -> *`Options...`*,
2. unwind *`Miscellaneous compatibility options`*,
3. check *`Special keys (Ctrl+Alt+<key>) handled in a server`*.

Please, be aware it will also disable some other shortcuts (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> used to switch video modes).

Comment: Thanks for your help.
In fact I was looking for Ctrl + Alt + F4 but I wrote Ctrl + Shift + F4 :(