# How do I make Ctrl+Alt+F7 keyboard shortcut work in IntelliJ on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

There is already a partial solution to the problem [documented on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/412046/unable-to-use-intellij-idea-keyboard-shortcuts-on-ubuntu).

Unfortunately, it is not working for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-7]</kbd> keys.
There was a solution for that in [Ubuntu 13.04 and eralier](http://outrospective.org/wordpress/2012/03/get-your-ctrlaltfx-keyboard-shortcuts-back-in-ubuntu-11-10/) to enable "Special keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd>) handled in a server" in Keyboard Layout -> Options -> Miscellaneous compatibility options. 
There is also a general [X11 xorg solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34158/rebinding-disabling-ctrlaltf), but does nor work with Ubuntu 14.04 since it has no /etc/X11/xorg.conf.
Also, I cannot find the corresponding [option in gnome-tweek-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/360378/how-to-access-the-keyboard-layout-options-in-13-10), which is supposed to be used in this case according to Ubuntu developers.

How do I enable special keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F[1-7]</kbd> in the server so that IntelliJ shortcuts work in Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: It'd be simpler to configure the IntelliJ shortcuts, IMHO: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-keyboard-shortcuts.html

Comment: @muru Not in my case :/ I am using Windows, Mac and Linux depending on where I am (work, home, underground). I would like to have one short-cut map in IntelliJ.

Comment: @muru Yeah, but I can not copy it to my co-workers box when I am pair-programming with him. I really wanna use the default keymap.

Comment: Try out http://askubuntu.com/q/50233/158442

Comment: Also, there's an X option called DisableVTSwitch, or something, which will disable all thr ctrl-alt-f* shortcuts (I'd imagine chvt will still work).

Comment: @muru How do I change that option in Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: @Wojtek : Is your Alt key registering in Intellij. I am using RubyMine which I think both are related. It is not registering things like `Alt + Button 1 Click`.

Comment: @ZiyanJunaideen what do you mean, sorry?

Comment: For anyone like me who is here because their GUI just vanished and they have no clue how to get it back, ctrl+alt+F1 fixes it. You might have to click on the window again using your mouse if you are in a VM.

Answer (score 9):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> (rather than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. you can change the default ubuntu keymap setting by  setting->keyboard-> shortcuts->windows->move windows change "move window" shortcut and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> in android studio. It works.

Comment: Thanks Manish, but I do not want to change my shortcuts. I wanna keep them as they are.

Comment: @Wojtek He is telling you how to change Ubuntu's use of the Alt-F7 key combination to some other key combination. That leaves it free for Intellij to use.

Comment: @LeeMeador I believe he is talking about Andoid Studio (IntelliJ), not Ubuntu and using different shortcuts, not the detault ones, which is what I do not want to do. The only way to disable Alt+F7 in Ubuntu is via already mentioned DisableVTSwitch, but I do not know how to do it in Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu 14.02 you can change those workspace keys by

1. "Start"-menu > System Tools > dconf Editor
2. Navigate to org > gnome > desktop > wm > keybindings

Click on the key you want to "give its freedom" and change it. I changed F7 to F7.

After that IntelliJ recognized the key combination

Comment: I cannot see any Ctrl+Alt+F[1-9] values in there. Also, all names switch-to-workspace-[1-12] are ['disabled'] already.

Answer (score 2):

As Lee Meador mentioned, dconf-Editor should have the binding. It might be the case that it's under a different package though. For me the bindings for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F*</kbd> are under org.gnome.mutter.wayland.keybindings.

Comment: On my system they also were under that package. You can search for the `switch-to-session-<X>` shortcuts with the search tool of dconf-editor.

Answer (score 1):

Lee's answer points in the right direction, but in Ubuntu 17.04 there is no "F7" keyboard mapping, so you cannot map it to "F7".  However, the following did the trick for me:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/begin-move '["<Control><Shift><Alt><Super>F7"]'
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/begin-resize '["<Control><Shift><Alt><Super>F8"]'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it! I found it!
(I copied my answer to [this chat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1079476/how-to-change-ctrlaltf7-in-ubuntu-18-04) too)

There is a simple command line to disable the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F [1-7]</kbd>.
I don't know which versions of ubuntu support this command line, but on Ubuntu 18.10, it seems to work well.

```
setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none
```

But the command line only seems to work when it is executed after the login: After each lock/logout, the shorcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F [1-7]</kbd>. Are enabled again.
I tried to put this line in "Startup Application" and also in ".profile". Either way, it doesn't work.

So I created a new shortcut that executes this command by pressing (for example) <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. And it works fine!
I just must do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> after each login, and if after I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> there isn't any black screens!

Does someone know a better way to run a command line after the login?
Am I obliged to do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> after each login?