# How to change Ctrl+Alt+F7 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, intellij

Can I change the schortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> in Ubuntu 18.04 ?

If yes, how ?

Answer (score 2):

I found it! I found it!
(I copied my answer to [this chat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/515883/how-do-i-make-ctrlaltf7-keyboard-shortcut-work-in-intellij-on-ubuntu-14-04) too)

There is a simple command line to disable the shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F [1-7]</kbd>.
I don't know which versions of ubuntu support this command line, but on Ubuntu 18.10, it seems to work well.

```
setxkbmap -option srvrkeys:none
```

But the command line only seems to work when it is executed after the login: After each lock/logout, the shorcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F [1-7]</kbd>. Are enabled again.
I tried to put this line in "Startup Application" and also in ".profile". Either way, it doesn't work.

So I created a new shortcut that executes this command by pressing (for example) <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. And it works fine!
I just must do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> after each login, and if after I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> there isn't any black screens!

Does someone know a better way to run a command line after the login?
Am I obliged to do <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> after each login?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I just spent 1 hour of my life on this, so here you go...

> Does someone know a better way to run a command line after the login?

So, generally, to run something when new xsession is starting you simply add it to ~/.xsession or ~/.xsessionrc or /etc/X11/Xsession.d/... . However, this approach won't work on 18.04.

It seems that if you go the usual 'Xsession way', your 'setxkbmap' will execute fine, BUT these settings will be later overwritten by something else. After a bunch of digging I accidentally came across this 'keyboard-configuration' thing that has some options in /etc/default/keyboard. It is also mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1182328/ubuntu-18-04-kb-layout-xkb-options-are-ignored-after-reboot). So, long story short, this works:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
...
XKBOPTIONS="srvrkeys:none"
...
```

Comment: Yep ... at least an hour here too, except it would have much much much longer had I not found your answer.  This works on Ubuntu 20.04.  Thank you!!!